# How to format USB in Windows that is formatted in EXT4

Tags: windows, formatting

How do I format my USB in Windows? about 2 GB of it is formatted in (I think) EXT4, while the rest (about ~2.3MB) is formqatted in FAT32. What do I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you want to use it for? With what type of system?

Not sure how you ended up with ext4. That's used with Linux. The FAT32 partition is reserved.

If you don't need the data on it, then erase the whole disk and format it with the filesystem that is needed for the device/system you plan to use it with. You can't go wrong with MS-DOS (FAT) or exFAT. They are the most portable because they are somewhat old-school MS Windows formats, and are, therefore, supported by the majority of Systems on all devices.

Comment: I don't know how to erase the disk. I don't know why it's linux either, a friend gave it to me and said it was a linux USB but I need a different kind of linux so I need to format it so I can put the installer on it.

Comment: Oh... I found out why... It must have been formatted or partitioned improperly, because it has the 2.3 MB partition in the middle of a bunch of unallocated space.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below steps to format your USB drive under Windows.

Since its currently formatted as ext4 I dont believe it will show up in your computer as an available drive.

1.) Right click on "my computer" or whatever Microsoft is calling it these days.

2.) Click on Manage.

3.) Locate Disk Management.

From there you can delete the partitions you dont want and re-format as NTFS.

Comment: For me the missing step was right clicking on the old "Volume" in Disk Management and deleting it. From there I was able to create a new volume and format it as exFAT.